# Translate from CodeIgniter Active Record model to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: codeigniter, model, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am a CodeIgniter trying to adopt Laravel, however, I have been having a lot of problems understanding how to use Eloquent.

I suspect that if I could figure out how to translate some of my CodeIgniter Model methods to Laravel Eloquent I might be able to get on better. Hopefully, this will help others with the same problem.

Could anybody please rewrite the following from CodeIgniter to Eloquent:

```
public function get_products($product_id = NULL, $category_id = NULL, $limit = NULL)
{
    $this->db->select('*, product.id AS product_id');
    $this->db->from('product');
    $this->db->join('product_unit', 'product.source_unit_id = product_unit.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('stock_levels', 'product.stock_level_id = stock_levels.id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('categories', 'product.category_id = categories.cat_id', 'left');
    if(isset($product_id)) {
        $this->db->where('product.id', $product_id);
    }
    if(isset($category_id)) {
        $this->db->where('product.category_id', $category_id);
    }
    if(isset($limit)) {
        $this->db->limit($limit);
    }
    #$this->db->order_by('categories.cat_name', 'ASC');
    $this->db->order_by('categories.cat_name', 'ASC');
    $this->db->order_by('product.name', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approximate version of your query, there should be some things to tweak, but I hope you get the idea:

```
public function get_products($product_id = NULL, $category_id = NULL, $limit = NULL)
{
   $query = Product::leftJoin('product_unit', 'source_unit_id', '=', 'product_unit.id')
                    ->leftJoin('stock_levels', 'stock_level_id', '=', 'stock_levels.id')
                    ->leftJoin('categories', 'category_id', '=', 'categories.cat_id');

    if(isset($product_id)) {
        $query->where('product.id', $product_id);
    }

    if(isset($category_id)) {
        $query->where('product.category_id', $category_id);
    }

    if(isset($limit)) {
        $query->limit($limit);
    }

    #$this->db->order_by('categories.cat_name', 'ASC');
    $query->orderBy('categories.cat_name', 'ASC');
    $query->orderBy('product.name', 'ASC');

    dd( $query->toSql() ); /// this line will show you the sql generated and die // remove it to execute the query

    return $query->get()->toArray();
}
```

Comment: So, for something like this you ignore any `hasMany()`, `belongsTo()` etcs?

Comment: Is this the Product model? And if so, does that mean that `$query = Product`... is self referencing?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this thing, this is just one that has a visual representation like yours. But we can, of course, change it all to be very "Eloquent". $query = Product is just creating an instance of the query builder, so we can use further.

Comment: I don't think that you'd want to use Eloquent for this.  This method would give you results that would be much easier to work with.  If using Eloquent, you'd end up with a collection of products and each product in that collection would have collections of units, stock levels, and categories.  Since you are left joining, I'm assuming there is going to be null values in some cases, so those collections of units, stock levels, and categories would have different number of results, you'd have an impossible time of figuring out what goes with what.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro: Would it be possible to another way of doing this? Just for the sake of completeness? | Can anyone explain when / what the purpose is of using Eloquent then?

Comment: @atwright147, I don't see a way of improving this. You could find an obscure, but better way to improve `the first line`, but those wheres and orderbys won't change and, as @user1669496 said, left joins are a problem, afaik hasMany and belongsTo would give you no nulls.